# cakephp 2.3 - change password method error

Tags: php, cakephp

i have this method for user password changing in the controller (UsersController.php):

```
public function changepass() {
    if($this->User->exists()) {         
        $new_pass = $this->request->data['User']['newpass'];
        $repeat_pass = $this->request->data['User']['newrepeat'];
            if($new_pass == $repeat_pass) {
                $this->User->saveField('password',$new_pass);
                $this->Session->flash(__('Updated successfully'));
                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'dashboard'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->flash(__('Passwords did not match'));
                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'changepass'));
            }

    }
}
```

and this view (changepass.ctp):

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->create();

    echo $this->Form->input('newpass',array('type'=>'text','label'=>array('text'=>'Enter new password'))); 

    echo $this->Form->input('newrepeat',array('type'=>'text','label'=>array('text'=>'Confirm new password'))); 
?>

    <button type="submit">Save</button>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

But this does not seem to work,and i cannot actually understand why. Can you help me? Do you see what's wrong here?

Thank you in advance guys!

Comment: You are not hashing your new password. I also recommend reading http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/ and the documentation on it in the cookbook.

Comment: This is not that it's saved but un-hashed,this is not saved at all in the database. (I'll read the link you posted,hoping to find out). Anyone else ??

Comment: You need to use id field in form + save() + id key in array instead of saveField() if you do not set $this->User->id. Otherwise Cake assumes an insert instead of update.

Comment: you're right my friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the user id before checking if the user exists

Assuming you are trying to change the password of the currently logged in user and assuming your user id column is named `user_id`

```
$this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('user_id');
```

It would be easier if you could be a little specific on why it does not work (does it show the password did not match message etc.)

Comment: Actually,this was the problem,the fact that i did not manually set the user id,thank you!!

Comment: also,just for the record:There are some bugs also in the code. For exampe,the code $this->Session->flash() does not work. The right one is $this->Session->setFlash(). After that,i believe everything else is just fine :)